# Backbone model validation doesn't reject an invalid value

Tags: backbone.js

Why doesn't this simple example  work:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: 0  
    },

    validate: function(atts, options){
        if(atts.title < 0) {
            return console.log('tekst');
        }
    }

});

var person1 = new Person();
person1.on('invalid',function(model,error){
    alert(model.get('title') +error );
});
```

When I set an incorrect value with `person1.set({title: -1},{validate: true})`, the console returns an error message but the model is still changed to -1.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from validate; if
>   they are invalid, return an error of your choosing. It can be as
>   simple as a string error message to be displayed, or a complete error
>   object that describes the error programmatically.

You need to return **a value**, not just have a return statement. Try this:

```
validate: function(atts, options){
    if(atts.title < 0) {
        return "can't be negative!";
    }
}
```